# Can a Yachid follow his own opinion in a Tzibbur?

Tags: halacha, tzibur-community, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, masechet-yevamot

The Gemara in Yevamos (13b) says that there is a prohibition to make "Agudos Agudos", different groups of people following different rulings.

However, the Gemara says that this is forbidden only if two people on one Beis Din issue conflicting rulings, not if there are two Beis Dins issuing conflicting rumors.

What if there's a Beis Din but a Chacham SheHigiya LeHoraah (or just a person with a different Rov) does things his own way. Does he violate Lo Sisgodedu?

Comment: Can you be more specific, give a an example

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated#comment6496_797

Comment: @sam I'm a Talmid of R' Yossi (or R' Yossi himself) and want to eat chicken and milk in my house or in a party in a city which doesn't hold that way. May I?

Comment: See chullin 18b with regards to this,with bavel and Eretz Yisroel.